# Firebase Crashlytics - Issue number

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

Just moved finally from using Fabric to using Firebase to track our app crashes, and the only thing I'm missing are the issue numbers, that I'm used to from Fabric. Is there a way to see issue numbers on Firebase Crashlytics?

Before, on Fabric: (you can see the numbers marked with green)

[image]

And on Firebase, can't find them:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mike from Firebase here. Currently, we don't have issue numbers included within Crashlytics.

I'll let the team know you'd like to see them added in.

Comment: Thanks, that would be very useful! We are using the issue numbers in our crash fixing process as a way to identify the crash and as a naming convention. I'm sure more developers do too.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback again, much appreciated.

Comment: Comment reinforcement. Would be great to have the issue number included!

Comment: We no longer have a way to refer to a specific crash, please add back the issue ID field, it's important to have that! Why is it taking a year to just display this field somewhere?!

Comment: We would really appreciate a short issue ID with an easy way to copy it and link back to it. Perhaps the last 8 of the one available in the URL

Comment: What's really interesting is variants have nice short IDs like `#3bc2` and `#fe19`. While these probably are not globally unique, there is some prior art within the product to have these short unique IDs

Answer (score 3):

Whilst (as Mike Bonnell said) there are no issue numbers, you can use the issue ID in the URL bar as an identifier if essential, although it is much longer.

For example, for the issue URL `https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<project name>/crashlytics/app/android:<package name>/issues/5bcc240cf8b88c29639a0bcd` the ID is `5bcc240cf8b88c29639a0a8e`.

Comment: You cannot, if you have multiple accounts logged in (and this is very common), because your link is now `https://console.firebase.google.com/u/<user_number>/project/<project name>/crashlytics/app/android:<package name>/issues/5bcc240cf8b88c29639a0bcd` the ID is 5bcc240cf8b88c29639a0a8e . And short links don't work, they're personal. It sucks.